# How to change fontsize of \cmpdref

Tags: fontsize, chemstyle, chemnum

I was using `chemstyle` package, but for some utilities I moved to `chemnum`. With `chemstyle` I used

```
\renewcommand*{\schemerefformat}{\fontsize{8pt}{8pt}\textbf{}}
```

in order to reduce the font size of numbers in schemes. I couldn't find this option or equal in `chemnum` which use `\cmpdref{key}` to label a molecule.

Is there a way reduce the font size in `\cmpdref`?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Can you add an example of usage? With a `\documentclass` command and the necessary packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For versions prior to version 1.0**

In the `chemnum` package the format is controlled by three options: `cmpd-style` and `ref-style` which control the standard form and the form placed with `\cmpdref` and `cmpd-weight` which sets the labels bold or normal for both. All of them can be set with `\cmpdsetup`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{relsize}

\cmpdsetup{
  cmpd-style=\textsmaller,
  ref-style=\sffamily\textsmaller,
  cmpd-weight=normal}

\begin{document}

Text \cmpd{blah} Text

\cmpdref{test}
\cmpdref{blub}
\includegraphics{./scheme-tmp.ps}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**For version 1.0**

With version 1.0 (released 2014/03/12) there have been a number of changes both to commands and options. Here is a solution for version 1.0:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: on }
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[runs=2]{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{relsize}

\setchemnum{
  format = \smaller ,
  replace-style = \sffamily , % this acts /additionally/ to format!
}

\begin{document}

Text \cmpd{blah} Text

\replacecmpd{test}
\replacecmpd{blub}
\includegraphics{./scheme-tmp.ps}

\end{document}
```